# Why do I get a reference error when assigning to a variable without the var keyword?

Tags: javascript

This came up at work today. Take the following assignment, commonly used to initialize a variable.

```
// bill is undeclared
var bill = bill || [];
```

The value assigned to `bill` is `[]`.

Why does this fail with a reference error when you omit the `var` keyword?

```
// bill is undeclared
bill = bill || [];
```

Comment: are you in strict mode?

Comment: Because `bill || []` is... not defined.

Comment: variable names declarations are hoisted.

Comment: In any case, if that is "commonly used", then people are "commonly stupid". `var bill = bill || []` is nonsensical. Just `var bill = [];` will suffice.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the form in the question is not at all uncommon in client-side libraries (though I agree that it's probably pointless in a lot of cases)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol assume that `bill` is defined in another JS file and that if it exists we want to use it. Simply assigning the variable to a new array overwrites anything that might've been assigned in another file.

Comment: @jeremysawesome But `var bill` already does that.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol more on this "commonly stupid" pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963779/whats-the-name-of-google-analytics-async-design-pattern-and-where-is-it-used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still haven't got an answer so:

```
var bill = bill || [];
```

is interpreted exactly as if it had been written:

```
var bill;
bill = bill || [];
```

Note that because the reference to `bill` is after its declaration, there's no exception. It's `undefined` of course so it'll be set to the empty array.

If another file had been included, then if `bill` is already a property of the global object then the `var` does nothing. In particular, the value of the existing global is not affected by the `var` declaration. The assignment would stick with any non-falsy value.

There are situations where this can happen in a local context. Some build-time code preprocessors may combine separate fragments into a wrapper function. In such cases, the same behavior would happen except that there aren't any global variables involved. Furthermore, if the intention is *explicitly* to create a global, then you'd probably want

```
window.bill = window.bill || [];
```

just to make things unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. I think what is throwing me off is the concept of implicit globals. Why `bill = 3;` will work without a var... but `bill = bill || 3;` will not.

Comment: Well without a `var`, if there's no declared symbol "bill" then the right-hand side will therefore be a reference error. (Hold on, I'm going to look something up to make sure I'm saying it correctly.)

Comment: @jeremysawesome when you're not in "strict" mode, the undefined "bill" on the **left** side of the assignment operator is OK.  It's the reference on the **right** side that causes the reference error.

Comment: ok. So it seems as if JS doesn't actually create the implicit global until the assignment is executed. Since the assignment itself has a "reference" to something that is undefined then the assignment doesn't succeed and the *implicit global is never created*. I would've thought it would follow the same pattern as the `var` code. Create the variable, then execute the assignment.

Comment: would you make reference to the fact that, unlike the explicit variable declaration, an implicit global is not created until the assignment is executed?

Comment: @jeremysawesome I'm reading and re-reading the spec trying to figure out where it says that; the spec is really obtuse.

Comment: @jeremysawesome OK if you go through 11.13.1 (Simple Assignment), you'll see that the `GetValue()` call for the right-hand side is called before the call to `PutValue()`. It's inside `PutValue()` that the special case for non-"strict" implicit globals lives.